# Unable to resolve ANR in android

Tags: android

Wen i install my apk file on android device and after installation wen i hit the open button my application does not start and shows force close.

The logcat output of my application is shown below :

```
    09-28 12:14:57.651: INFO/ActivityManager(124): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.biz.mlm/.SplashScreen }

09-28 12:14:57.660: WARN/ActivityManager(124): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.biz.mlm/.SplashScreen } from ProcessRecord{44ffa660 1130:com.android.packageinstaller/10026} (pid=1130, uid=10026) requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

09-28 12:14:57.672: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1130): Shutting down VM

09-28 12:14:57.672: WARN/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.biz.mlm/.SplashScreen } from ProcessRecord{44ffa660 1130:com.android.packageinstaller/10026} (pid=1130, uid=10026) requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1298)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.onClick(InstallAppProgress.java:224)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-28 12:14:57.700: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 12:14:57.740: WARN/ActivityManager(124):   Force finishing activity com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress
```

Please help me by guiding me about what I have done wrong

EDIT :

The permissions in my manifest are :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/> -->
    <application android:icon="@drawable/biz_logo"
        android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS">
```

After this also it is behaving same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the permission

```
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

to your manifest file.

Barry

Comment: Please see the edits..i have added android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS but still same response of application

Answer (score 1):

The logcat output has everything you need to know :-)

Your app basically is writing contacts but it does not have permissions to do so (in Android, applications need to be given permissions explicitly for various operations).

Edit the file AndroidManifest.xml to include the following line/XML element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

within the

```
<manifest>
```

XML element, and then rebuild, reinstall and rerun.

For more information, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Answer (score 0):

yes i rebuilt it.my mistake was i have written in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />` and also inside the application tag like this

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS">
```

so i was getting force close.

This permission should be written **only once** in the manifest file